# jboss-cli : How do I read one specific system property using jboss-cli?

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jboss-cli

I'm new to jboss-cli and working through the 'jboss-cli recipes'.

**Question**

How do I read *one specific property* using jboss-cli? E.g.

- jboss.home.dir (e.g. "-Djboss.home.dir=/path/to/my/jboss")
- Xmx ("-Xmx=4G")

**Context**

The "CLI Recipes" documentation has this helpful example to get *all* system properties. However its 'too much infomration'. I want to script reading one specific property.

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/CLI+Recipes#CLIRecipes-

> Overview of all system properties in JBoss AS7+ including OS system
>   properties and properties specified on command line using -D, -P or
>   --properties arguments.

```
Standalone
[standalone@IP_ADDRESS:9999 /] /core-service=platform-mbean/type=runtime:read-attribute(name=system-properties)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link pointed me to the answer: I can use a groovy script to get the values. From what I see the "jboss-cli command line" does not offer this flexibility.

https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/AdvancedCLIScriptingWithGroovyRhinoJythonEtc

**Solution**

Here's a solution for jboss home.

[For memory you can get results from "/core-service=platform-mbean/type=memory/:read-attribute(name=heap-memory-usage)"

**bash**

```
#!/bin/sh
# Note: must set jbbin to 'jboss home /bin'
groovy -cp $jbbin/client/jboss-cli-client.jar readJbossHome.groovy
```

**Groovy**
Note: this is 'quick and dirty'.

```
import org.jboss.as.cli.scriptsupport.*  

cli = CLI.newInstance()  
cli.connect()  

// Define properties
myParentProp="system-properties"
myProp="jboss.home.dir"

// Retrieve and pluck values
result = cli.cmd("/core-service=platform-mbean/type=runtime:read-resource(recursive=true,include-runtime=false)")

myResult = result.getResponse().get("result")
myParentVal = myResult.get(myParentProp)
myVal = myParentVal.get(myProp)

// Print out results
println "Property detail ${myProp}  is ${myVal}"


cli.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do a :

> :resolve-expression(expression=${jboss.home.dir})

Answer (score 3):

You can use the cli like this:

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c --command=/system-property=MY_PROPERTY:read-resource
```

you  get an output like this:

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c --command=/system-property=MY_PROPERTY:read-resource
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => {"value" => "4.0"}
}
```

which you can extract by piping into something like this:

```
<cli command>  | grep "{\"value\"" | sed "s/.*value\" => \"\([^\"]*\)\".*/\1/"
```

its a bit ugly, and there are some nasty edge cases if the values were to be something like "value" => "value ="   or something hideous.
In general this works OK.

Change the sed command to be a bit more specific to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

## jboss-cli

If you have a cli command like ehsavoie suggested `:resolve-expression(expression=${jboss.home.dir})` and want to use the content of the **"result"** property within `jboss-cli` you can save it in a variable. You can use backticks (**`**) to evaluate expressions.

#### simple expression

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] :resolve-expression(expression=${jboss.home.dir})
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => "/home/user/wildfly"
}
```

#### use in valiable

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] set wildflydirectory=`:resolve-expression(expression=${jboss.home.dir})`
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] echo $wildflydirectory
/home/user/wildfly
```

## PowerShell

If you happen to use the PowerShell you can use a one-liner to extract even deeply nested results with the help of the cli's `--output-json` option and PowerShell's `ConvertFrom-Json` cmdlet. In this way the parsing problem from James Roberts's approach with grep and sed are gone.

```
$value=(Invoke-Expression "./jboss-cli.ps1 -c --command=':resolve-expression(expression=`${jboss.home.dir})' --output-json" | ConvertFrom-Json).result
```

It is a bit tricky to quote the command and escape the correct PowerShell special characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it via Wildfly management rest call.

- http://localhost:9990/management
- POST
- Headers = Content-Type:application/json
- Body =
  {
  "operation":"resolve-expression",
  "expression":"${jboss.home.dir}"
  }

Answer (score 0):

With newer Teiid DOCs I have found some useful information I thought this might be helpful to share to people coming across a similar usecase

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.3/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/configure_system_properties_using_the_management_cli

Helps Adding, Removing & Reading System Properties with jboss-cli